# DIV not showing in right place

Tags: css, html

I have the following page:

```
http://sikni8.com/mypage/text.htm
```

The copyright section is not showing in the right place. I would like that to be right below the white box with the text "TEXT" inside it.

I tried all different method, but none is working! any idea?

Thanx

Edit: Alright, if you visit the above website, do you see the white box expanding from the left of the page to the right? I want that box to be below the white square with the curve bottom. makes sense? If not i will post a pic. Thanx

Comment: You need to learn to setup your layout properly with a better naming convention. Learn to use a wrapper. Google is your friend.

Comment: Im still pretty new to this site so still learning the way :)... but def alot of ppl did help me out! will definitely do that... and the naming convention is temporary until i get the layout i want :)

The top DIV is working fine where the animated image is at... but the bottom div is overlapping another DIV... :(

Comment: Please expand your question and be more descriptive, I am not sure what you mean. Do you want the "plo" DIV - "NurForNas Home | About | Copyright | Disclaimer | Contact" to not be overlapped and should appear as a solid white rectangle with nothing over it, is that the problem?

Comment: I expanded my question, hope it helps. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3 containers `float:left; width:100%;` for the 3 majors sections of your website.
**for example:**
 `<header>` for your header 
`<div id="content">` for your content
`<footer>` for your footer.
 Put your white box text into the content div and the copyright into de footer. This way, all three section will appear below each other.
Hope this help.

Comment: So pretty much <header></header> and <div id="content"></div> and <footer></footer>? Isn't it HTML5 syntax? i can still use it for the older version? Thanx

Comment: I did not have to use it but SIMON, i must say u just made my day!!! the Float: left and width: 100% worked like a charm!!!! THANKS SO MUCH! buy u a beer? or rep is GOOD? lol

Comment: Yes it's html5. This will work in the older version if you add this in the head of your document http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/. This will define the html5 tag for the older browser who don't natively suport them.